# Как сделать, чтобы не вызывался alert?

Tags: iframe, javascript

На странице есть iframe.

Как сделать, чтобы не вызывался alert не с главного окна, не с iframe?

```
window.alert = function (){return false}
myIFrime.contentWindow.alert = function (){return false}
```

Так или у iframe по-другому надо?

Comment: > не с главного окна, не с iframe

**ни** с главного окна, **ни** с iframe

Comment: ага. спасибо. это действитель в тему

Answer (score 1):

Alert вызывается, только если указать, чтобы он вызывался.
 Если не хотите, чтобы он вызывался, не добавляйте его в код.

Comment: iframe имеет свою структуру DOM со своим alert(), поэтому в нем тоже надо блочить: iframe.contentWindow.alert. Если конечно политика безопасности Вам позволят это сделать: содержимое сайта и iframe должны иметь один домен. Поэтому, по идее, вы верно написали ответ в вопросе.